# Set step as succeeded on timeout in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a way to declare a step timeout in a GitHub Actions to be a 'successful job'? I want to build an executable and run it for a couple of minutes - if it doesn't crash, the pipeline should tell me the test passed / succeeded. It's certainly possible to use something like timeout in bash - but I'm trying to figure out a cross platform solution, hence trying to accomplish this with "pure actions".

Answer (score 3):

Example of job succeeding on timeout.

```
      - name: no timeout
        run: timeout 10 python ./sleep.py || code=$?; if [[ $code -ne 124 && $code -ne 0 ]]; then exit $code; fi
```

See this [example repo](https://github.com/meroware/timeout-and-failed-github-action-example/blob/master/.github/workflows/timeout-example.yaml) and [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641822/run-command-with-timeout-in-github-workflow).

Comment: yeah, I saw this, works great on *nix distributions - but I was hoping for a GitHub actions 'native' method that would be a cross platform solution. My current bandaid is a python script that abstracts the OS scripting.

Comment: You can include this but it is intended to fail as an error. `timeout-minutes: 10 ` FWIW the bash solution works well for me in a Docker container.